# break line not working with ajax response

Tags: jquery

I have a  tag on my page which I want to populate with an answer I get from my ajax processing. I would like to have line breaks in my span.

My page content looks like this:

```
<span id="extraitems"></span >
```

The part returned in ajax looks like this:

```
$extraitems = "this is a test to break line /n Second line";
echo json_encode(array('extraitems' => $extraitems, 'success' => true));
```

and then on my page I do this:

```
if(data.extraitems){
    $("#extraitems").text(data.extraitems);
}
```

I want my extraitems span to look like this:

This is a test to break line

Second line

Instead it looks like this:
This is a test to break line /n Second line

I have tried /r/n, < br > and other combinations but they are always displayed inline instead of doing the line break...

Comment: sorry I did not put it correctly in my code example but I used \n in my actual code and the result is the same. It doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should replace `/n` by `<br>` and then using:

```
$("#extraitems").html(data.extraitems);
```

Instead of:

```
$("#extraitems").text(data.extraitems);
```

And this is [my jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/HP8fn/). Hope this help, mate.